# Text shadow on SVG text element is always white on mobile Safari ...

Tags: text, svg, safari, shadow

I'm converting the main banner of a website from image to a SVG based. The code is basically this one:

```
<svg fill="url(#gradient-5)" width="100%" height="100%" style="transform: scale(1);">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient-5" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
              <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#fff"></stop>
              <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#888"></stop>
              <stop offset="69%" stop-color="#fff"></stop>
              <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#fff"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="75%">Sample text</text>
</svg>
```

And so, I see the text with the original gradient. The problem is that the original text had text-shadow, so I added text shadow with CSS:

```
.svg-main-banner text {
    text-shadow: #FF0000 0 3px;
}
```

But the text shadow is always white on mobile Safari. It's OK on all the other devices/browsers. Any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: That seems like a bug. You should add your shadow using a SVG filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Michael Mullany, you could replace the CSS text-shadow with an equivalent SVG filter. You can create a drop shadow using a SVG filter of the form...

```
<filter id="drop-shadow">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="[radius]"/>
    <feOffset dx="[offset-x]" dy="[offset-y]" result="offsetblur"/>
    <feFlood flood-color="[color]"/>
    <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
    <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </feMerge>
</filter>
```

Just fill in the radius, offset-x, offset-y, and color values. In your example, the SVG code would become...

```
<svg fill="url(#gradient-5)" width="100%" height="100%" style="transform: scale(1);">
    <defs>
        <filter id="drop-shadow">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="0"/>
            <feOffset dx="0" dy="3" result="offsetblur"/>
            <feFlood flood-color="#FF0000"/>
            <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
        <linearGradient id="gradient-5" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
              <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#fff"></stop>
              <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#888"></stop>
              <stop offset="69%" stop-color="#fff"></stop>
              <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#fff"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="75%" filter="url(#drop-shadow)">Sample text</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Great :) ... I played with this a little bit, and modifying the "stdDeviation" value for achieving blur - did the trick :) ... thanks a lot :)